# How to delete old copy of objects C#

Tags: c#, image, copy, out-of-memory

I get an Image from a public variable, after each operation on this image I create a copy on to the global varialble so that the UI can update it.

But ater some time I got an out of memory exception, any ideas?
befor i tryed it without copy, but then I got an exception as I want to reload the Image, it was already in use.

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(transmit_pic);
    t.Start();
}
protected Bitmap CopyBitmap(Bitmap source)
{
    return new Bitmap(source);
}
private void transmit_pic()
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(img);
    Bitmap bm = CopyBitmap(b);
    int size_X = bm.Width;
    int size_Y = bm.Height;

    int px = 255;
    Color Green  = Color.FromArgb(0,255,0);
    for (int h = 0; h < size_Y; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < size_X; w++)
        {
            px = (int)bm.GetPixel(w, h).G;
            if (px < 128)
            {
               // i shorted it a litel bit
               if(somethig not imprtend here){
                bm.SetPixel(w, h, Green);
                img = (Image)CopyBitmap(bm);
               }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.Write("DONE");
}
private void RELOAD_PIC_on_UI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers all have the solution for you but just to add some clarity:

In C# objects are managed meaning it is impossible to literally "delete old copy of objects"--they will be cleared whenever the framework's garbage collector decides to do so, which is not a deterministic process and depends on how much memory your computer has available.

That said, there are a few things that aren't managed by the framework, such as open file streams and images or database connections. The framework doesn't close these resources automatically, and as a result can't clear memory objects that use them. The purpose of the `IDisposable` interface and the `Dispose` method is to close these unmanaged resources so that the automatic garbage collection can clear the objects and free up the memory.

Comment: If you really have to trigger GC, you can use `GC.Collect()` to force it to run. I had to resort to that when dealing with multiple full-screen bitmaps in a small utility.

Comment: I did not know about `Collect`. Good to know. But, looks like it only triggers the normal collection routine, so still not a way to literally delete a specific object at a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the [Bitmap.Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and make sure there are no references to the old, unused image.

> Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the Image. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the Image object's Finalize method.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Bitmap.Dispose, in general it's a good habit to dispose objects which you no longer need.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use using directive with same as .Dispose() allows you to make your code more readable, also in many scenario you can directly use return inside a using directive so your object will dispose even you must return someting related with your : IDisposable object.

```
private void transmit_pic()
{
    using(Bitmap b = new Bitmap(img))
    using(Bitmap bm = CopyBitmap(b))
    {
        int size_X = bm.Width;
        int size_Y = bm.Height;

        int px = 255;
        Color Green  = Color.FromArgb(0,255,0);
        for (int h = 0; h < size_Y; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < size_X; w++)
            {
                px = (int)bm.GetPixel(w, h).G;
                if (px < 128)
                {
                   // i shorted it a litel bit
                   if(somethig not imprtend here){
                    bm.SetPixel(w, h, Green);
                    img = (Image)CopyBitmap(bm);
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.Write("DONE");
}
```

In your sample we disposed your both b and bm instances of Bitmap object.